# Not able to build POCO lib on VS13

Tags: visual-studio-2013, poco-libraries

I am getting build errors while compiling POCO first time with VS13. I think it is not compatible with VS13. Any idea, how to fix this without downgrading my Visual Studio?

```
C:\Users\as\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\poco-1.4.6p4> buildwin.cmd 110
```

> error MSB8020: The build tools for Visual Studio
>   2012 (Platform Toolset = 'v110') cannot be found. To build using the v110 build tools, please install Visual Studio 2012 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Upgrade
>   Solution...". [`C:\Users\asjaiswal\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\poco-1.4.6p4\Net\samples\WebSocketServer\WebSocketServer_vs110.vcxproj`]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Version 110 is Visual Studio 2012. VS 2013 is version 120 and those projects are not available in the releases yet.

VS 2013 support has been introduced in [develop](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco) branch, which also has (in addition to the old batch files) the [PowerShell build script](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/buildwin.ps1) (see [announcement](http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=6171)) which automatically detects available VS version if present.

**EDIT**: VS2013 projects are [available now](http://pocoproject.org/download/index.html).